# The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read data from a binary file using c#
This data is entered using code but I'm getting this exception

```
The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'.
```

And here is the code :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open);
                FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(path2, FileMode.CreateNew);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs2);
                while (br.PeekChar() != -1) 
                {
                    bw.Write(br.ReadInt32());
                    bw.Write(br.ReadString());
                }
                bw.Close();
                br.Close();

                fs2.Close();
                fs.Close();
```

the exception is in the peekChar line

Comment: You're trying to read random data and interpret it as unicode characters. Why? Stop using `PeekChar`.

Comment: are you trying to read it as UTF-8 encoded characters? if not use `br.readbytes(bytesize)` where bytesize is the size of the data you're reading (i.e. char's are 2 bytes, int32's are 32 bytes)

Comment: @Luaan what should i use instead ?

Comment: i'm reading strings that i don't know the length